# How to display radio buttons circle and text on same alignment text?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on `blazor asp.net .net core 7` . I face issue I can't displaying radio button circle  and text with same alignment .

I need to add alignment circle radio and text internal or external on same line

and add space between circle radio and text internal as image below .

what I try as below :

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-3 col-form-label">
            AccessType
        </label>

        <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="@appsdata.AccessType" class="form-control">
            @foreach (var option in rdaccessOptions)
            {
                <InputRadio Value="option" />

                <span> @option</span> <br />
            }
        </InputRadioGroup>

    </div>
```

Expected Result

[image: radio button not on same alignment text]

I apply answer below but nothing changed

it as it before without changes

so what I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS here: `display: flex; align-items: center` will align all of the items on the same line.

```
<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="@appsdata.AccessType" class="form-control" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
        @foreach (var option in rdaccessOptions)
        {
            <InputRadio Value="option" />

            <span> @option</span> <br />
        }
</InputRadioGroup>
```

Comment: can you show me please which place add it

Comment: can you show me how to add that by code details please

Comment: see last update answer

Comment: you can just add a style attribute to the outer container. `<InputRadioGroup style="display: flex; align-items: center">`

Comment: i do it exactly and nothing changed

Comment: maybe use an external stylesheet? `<InputRadioGroup class="center-align">...</InputRadioGroup> <style> .center-align {  display: flex; align-items: center; } </style>`